# How to change combo box size in JDateChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, swingx, jdatechooser

I have a problem with `JDateChooser`. If I increase `Dimension` or font size, it all increases in size but not combo box (Month). And this I can't read good month selected if I change font size more to 24.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pQC2.png]

Comment: That looks more like a (single row) list (a `JList`) than a combo box.

Comment: @Li Xang  I think you can use `setPreferredSize()` or `setMinimumSize()` for your jdatechooser combobox

Comment: any example code please? i am begginer